# MS Word macro, copying current paragraph text to clipboard

Tags: vba, ms-word

From this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212529) I found out how to create a macro that selects current paragraph text.

```
Sub SelectCurrentParagraph()
   Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
End Sub
```

But I ned this: When I put cursor inside a paragraph, macro will select paragraph text and copy it to clipboard. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will copy your selection but checking for `wdSelectionNormal` will skip frames, shapes etc:

```
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select

If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
    Selection.Copy
End If
```

Comment: That is, use just `Selection.Copy` if you want to copy anything that is selected

Answer (score 3):

You can move around the word using different units (ie wdParagraph, wdCharacter, wdLine).  this will select the current paragraph and copy to the clipboard.

```
Sub SelectCurrentParagraph()
    Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```